# What's the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was thus understandable that when a speaker at a recent meeting on Science and the Law held in San Diego by American Justice Department hinted that the technique might not deserve its aura of infallibilty, a law inforcement agent in the audience was later overheard calling him an unprintable name.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's quite a run-on sentence.

The meaning is that the speaker hinted that some technique was potentially flawed or imperfect.  That note by the speaker drew ire/agitation from a law enforcement agent in the audience, presumably one who was pro-technique.  The agent then proceeded to call the speaker an "unprintable name", presumably something vulgar.

Comment: There's nothing run-on about it; it just has many constituents that are made up of multiple words/sub-constituents.